# Why is there a different list of Apex Classes in Permission Set vs User Profile

Tags: salesforce

We have a custom application where the install includes a custom Permission Set. Our customer wants to grant those permissions with Profiles instead. Simple enough right, look at the permissions granted by the permission set and grant those same permissions with the profile.

But when we go into the Apex Classes section we have 9 classes in our Permission Set and of those only 4 are available for selection in the Profile.

Comment: You may get a better response on this other SE site that is really geared towards SFDC development - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: This might be related -  http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/149811/why-is-the-number-of-classes-listed-on-the-apex-class-access-page-for-a-profile